# Storing a tree structure in Django/Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, tree, hierarchy

I currently have these models, simplified for the sake of the question:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Post(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)

# the model in question
class Repost(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", related_name="children")
```

This works for fetching a Repost/Post by having the Profile object (although it's kinda inefficient), I can't traverse the whole tree as it would be too many queries.

So I've been reading on this subject, and it seems a Closure Table ([django-closuretree](http://django-closuretree.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) would be a good fit for my use cases:

1. Fetch Posts/Reposts for a certain Profile id
2. Fetch the whole Reposts tree for a certain Post id

The problem is most of the examples I've found (both for this library's docs and other articles discussing closure tables) mostly show how to retrieve the tree by having the root Repost id (which breaks my 2nd use case, as I only have the Post id)

PS: I'm a total noob when it comes to databases, so it's possible that this whole thing is a mess, in which I'm open to better ideas/architectures.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Something like reddit? Please bring some examples of your tree

Comment: isn't it a simple `Repost.objects.filter(post=my_post)` in your 2nd case or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, a link sharing platform, but not as the same scale as reddit of course. I'm mostly doing it for learning purposes (Instead of totally dumping postgres and using neo4j for example)

Comment: @Ali It fetches them as a flat list (doesn't keep the hierarchy). Do you mean I should construct the tree manually at the application level ?

Comment: Have you looked at `django-mptt`?

Comment: @RedJohn no I was just wondering. I never worked with tree structure using an orm before so I'm kinda thinking out loud.